# HttpHandler not working on site using different port

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I wrote a tiny HttpHandler, which works beautifully on my machine. However, once it was deployed to our staging server, requesting it gave an 404. I usually prefer configuring HttpHandlers in web.config, but this apparently didn’t work on the server: I fixed it by creating an .ashx file containing just the reference to my HttpHandler.

The .ashx file:

```
<% @ WebHandler class="MyNamespace.MyProject.MyHttpHandler" %>
```

The web.config setting:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="myhandler.ashx" type="MyNamespace.MyProject.MyHttpHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I assume the problem is caused by the server using a "special" port (888, don’t ask why) for the website. Can it be something else, what could I be missing?

Why am I seeing this behavior on the server? The HttpHandler runs fine on my local machine with configuration just in web.config, and here it’s also served from a “random” port, i.e. http://localhost:61229/myhandler.ashx.

Comment: Just check that IIS, under `Properties`->`Home Directory`->`Configuration` has the 'ashx' extension mapped appropriately ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure sounds like the web.config setting is not being found.

Is this IIS 7 by any chance? In that case make sure you're putting the handler in the <system.webServer> and its <handlers> section.

Comment: Excellent, lesson of the day: I didn't know HttpHandlers had to be set up in a different section on IIS7. Thanks! :)

Comment: And there's even a nifty tool in IIS to configure it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS7 but still want to keep your old IIS 6 config files.
By setting the Application pool to run in "Classic" mode, the handler will work again.

Not recommended, but sometimes this is a quick and good enough fix.